# $V \cong V \oplus V$ as $K$ vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am not very sure about the triviality of this problem but I can't see the solution. Problem is

If $V$ is a countable dimensional vector space over field $K$, then as $K$ vector spaces $V \cong V \oplus V$.

Comment: $K\neq K\oplus K$ so this statement is not true in full generality. If the dimension of $V$ is infinite then this is true though.

Comment: Since both spaces have countable infinite bases, there's a bijection between bases that induces an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Comment: I suppose you need some version of the axiom of choice for this actually.

Comment: @DanielRust: my answer makes it clear where the AC is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have an indexing $v_1,v_2,\ldots$ of a basis of $V$. We may choose such an indexing by the fact that the vector space has countable dimension;  by definition, dimension is the cardinality of the basis, so this means that a bijection of any basis with the natural numbers exists by assumption even in absence of the axiom of choice. Then an isomorphism is given by the linear map sending $v_{2k-1}\mapsto (v_k,0)$ and $v_{2k}\mapsto (0,v_k)$.

Comment: -1 for the claim on AC. You need AC$_\omega$.

Comment: @313 if the bijection is asserted to exist then there is no need to invoke any axioms to choose one. It's there for the taking. We're not well ordering an arbitrary set. Vector space has countable dimension $\implies$ exists a basis with a bijective map to the natural numbers $\implies$ I can use that map.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\dim V\oplus V=\dim V+\dim V=\dim V$ as $\dim V$ is infinite. Two vectors spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension. Here we are using that for any infinite cardinal number $A$ we have $A+A=A$ (meaning that for infinite sets $X$ we have a bijection between $X\times X$ and $X$).

Comment: The cardinality of $X \times X$ is, unsurprisingly, $|X| \times |X|$, not $|X|+|X|$.

Comment: They are (unsurprisingly) equal, so what is your pont @NajibIdrissi

Comment: Only if you assume the axiom of choice.